# Julia: Cannot install "Pkg" package in Julia

Tags: installation, package, julia

I have a problem with installing the "Pkg" package in Julia. 
The following is the error I get after using Pkg.add("Pkg"):

```
unknown package Pkg
macro expansion at ./pkg/entry.jl:53 [inlined]
(::Base.Pkg.Entry.##1#3{String,Base.Pkg.Types.VersionSet})() at ./task.jl:335

Stacktrace:
 [1] sync_end() at ./task.jl:287
 [2] macro expansion at ./task.jl:303 [inlined]
 [3] add(::String, ::Base.Pkg.Types.VersionSet) at ./pkg/entry.jl:51
 [4] (::Base.Pkg.Dir.##4#7{Array{Any,1},Base.Pkg.Entry.#add,Tuple{String}})() at ./pkg/dir.jl:36
 [5] cd(::Base.Pkg.Dir.##4#7{Array{Any,1},Base.Pkg.Entry.#add,Tuple{String}}, ::String) at ./file.jl:70
 [6] #cd#1(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::String, ::Vararg{String,N} where N) at ./pkg/dir.jl:36
 [7] add(::String) at ./pkg/pkg.jl:117
 [8] include_string(::String, ::String) at ./loading.jl:522
```

Also, it would be great if you tell me how I can find the Package directory of Julia in my mac. I am using Jupyter.

Comment: In Julia 1.0.0, the first one I have used, pressing the `]` key in the Julia REPL puts you into the package manager mode.  You may have already known that, but if not, that is a handy way to just `(v1.0) pkg> add PackageName`

Answer (score 4):

From Julia v0. 7 on, [Pkg is a standard library](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/Pkg/) (a package that ships with julia) and doesn't need to be installed. Just do `using Pkg` and you are good to go.

To your second question, by default you can find everything Julia related in your home folder under `~/.julia`.